# "Some of them" in French

Tags: synonymes

I have found several ways in which *some of them* might be rendered into French:

> ```
> 1. Quelqu'un d'eux
>
> 2. Quelqu'un d'entre eux
> ```

---

> ```
> 3. Certain d'eux
>
> 4. Certains d'eux
> ```

---

> ```
> 5. Certain d'entre eux
>
> 6. Certains d'entre eux
> ```

Now, with so much diversity on my hands, I simply don't know which one is correct and which one or ones is or are incorrect.

Perhaps someone can put some order back into things.

Comment: Note that if you mean *some of them*, you could rule out the singular (1), (3), and (5). And for the first pair, you want *quelques-un(e)s* /kɛlkəzœ̃, yn/.

Comment: We would rather say *L'un d'entre eux* for 'one of them' and *Ceux d'entre eux* for 'some of them'. They are not in the list but I think is the best translation. otherwise 6- *Certains d'entre eux* is also great

Comment: @Jonathan *Ceux d'entre eux* (defined) would not translate as  "some of them" (undefined) but as "those who..."

Comment: Quelques-uns parmi eux, parmi vous, nous. Also: quelque-unes parmi elles.

Comment: Certains parmi vous; certaines parmi vous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the [indefinite pronoun](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/certain#Pronom_ind.C3.A9fini) *certain* can be used at all times to mean "some".

*Quelqu'un d'eux / quelqu’un d'entre eux* is an  old-fashioned way, now perceived as literay, to mean *l'un d'eux* / *l'un d'entre eux*, for example :

> Quant aux sujets, si quelqu’un d’eux forme quelque résolution, il ne saurait l’exécuter sur l’État. ([*Lettres persanes*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6334100b/f308.item.r=quelqu%E2%80%99un%20d%E2%80%99eux), Montesquieu - 1721 )

> Quand le contingent d'une commune aura été réduit pour lesdites trois années, ou pour quelqu'une d'elles, le montant de la réduction sera rejeté sur toutes les... ([*Collection Générale Des Lois, Décrets, Arrêtés*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cOFgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA397&lpg=PA397&dq=%22quelqu%27une%20d%27elles%22&source=bl&ots=9Z_aX1zMTY&sig=K9Xtyfby-QUAhyBPKEBiI2H7TP8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS2KL-wN7UAhXSZFAKHePgAiQQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=%22quelqu%27une%20d%27elles%22&f=false), 1818)

In some cases *quelques-uns d'entre eux / quelques-unes d'entre elles*  would not mean a certain number of things /people but a small number of something ("a few"). It might not always make a difference, but at times you might not express what you had in mind.

[**Certain(e)s**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/certain#Pronom_ind.C3.A9fini) (pronom indéfini) is the word you need. When meaning an undefined part of a bigger quantity it is **always plural**.

> L'évolution des circonstances, ne serait-ce que démographiques, remet en question ces systèmes et peut même aboutir à remplacer certains d'eux par d'autres. ([*Une étrange alchimie: la dimension interculturelle dans la coopération*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=DEaDfAwsaWEC&pg=PA154&dq=%22certains%20d%27eux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22certains%20d%27eux%22&f=false), Jacques Pateau - 1998)

> On nous permettra de douter de l'exactitude de la plupart des conditions dans lesquelles Daudet aurait quitté le collège d'Alès, et même de nous inscrire en faux contre certaines d'elles. (*[La jeunesse d'Alphonse Daudet](https://books.google.fr/books?id=iThApGqnFa8C&pg=PA161&dq=%22certaines%20d%27elles%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22certaines%20d%27elles%22&f=false)*, Bruyere Marcel - 1965)

> Même si certains d'entre eux mentionnent qu'ils n'ont pas trop de travail pour l'instant, la plupart d'entre eux croient que la matière deviendra plus difficile ... ([*Aventuriers solitaires en quête d'utopie*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WS8QWhAZa3kC&pg=PA88&dq=%22certains%20d%27entre%20eux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22certains%20d%27entre%20eux%22&f=false), Jean-François Guillaume - 2005)

> Il est également possible de substituer des ressources naturelles à d'autres, car certaines d'entre elles (pétrole et forêts, par exemple) peuvent satisfaire plusieurs besoins et la plupart des besoins peuvent être satisfaits .. ([*Développement durable Les grandes questions*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GmuZaE9CPr4C&pg=PA303&dq=%22certaines%20d%27entre%20elles%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22certaines%20d%27entre%20elles%22&f=false), OECD, 2001).

The phrasing with *d'entre eux /elles* is much more frequent than the one without but as far as I know both are correct.

---

**Added:**
You may encounter *quelqu'uns* d'eux *quelqu'unes* d'elles (note the plural of *un**s**/une**s***) to mean *certains d'entre eux* but, even if some rare 20th c. occurrences can be found, this is extremely outdated and I would never use it nowadays :

> Ces insulaires étoient tous nuds, quelqu'uns d'eux se peignent le corps... (*[Mémoires géographiques, physiques et historiques](https://books.google.fr/books?id=fZsDuPAYkDIC&pg=PA149&dq=%22Quelqu%27uns%20d%27eux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Quelqu%27uns%20d%27eux%22&f=false)*, Jacques Philibert Rousselot de Surgy - 1767)

> Quelqu'uns d'eux ayans veu un François nommé le sieur Charles Fournier (qui est celuy mesme duquel j'ay appris cecy) tirer aux oyseaux,... ([*Histoire du Canada, et voyages que les Frères mineurs recollects y ont faicts pour la conversion des infidelles*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RZ9AZikaYbEC&pg=PA662&dq=%22Quelqu%27uns%20d%27eux%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Quelqu%27uns%20d%27eux%22&f=false), Gabriel Sagard - 1866)

> C'est un oiseau voyageur, qui part en octobre avec toutes les alouettes; on le voit alors, par paire, planer dans l'air sur quelqu'unes d'elles, ou quelques souris. (*[Manuel d'ornithologie domestique ou guide de l'amateur des oiseaux de voliere](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IUZ08GS8G3MC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=%22Quelqu%27unes%20d%27elles%22&source=bl&ots=oHYvdy7IiS&sig=l8Dczac21Zo3Q0s85G2IvzVjpA4&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsucHOm-DUAhUKM8AKHcfqCqYQ6AEIPDAH#v=onepage&q=%22Quelqu%27unes%20d%27elles%22&f=false)*, René-Primevère 1834)